# Used Uniswap to swap back assets to ETH in metamask wallet, but transaction is worth 0,00USD

Tags: uniswap

I tried to swap ERC-20 asset to ETH that was sitting on a randomcoin that i used to trade before, but the transaction just vanished the ETH it was supposed to transfer.

Did i miss something in the process of swapping using UniSwap ?

Txn ID: 0xbade5e963a61703afd47f1cf3f684656b8ac8d5eafa1b549ef9ce0f6d02d2263

When i check the recent transactions from the ERC-20 Token, it looks like all trasactions are worth 0ETH, what is exactly going on ?

Comment: Looks ok to me, you got 0.01 ETH, check "Internal transactions".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem the author describes does not exist, he just failed to notice ETH being sent to his wallet.

Comment: Metamask doesnt show any value in the transaction, it shows -0ETH instead of granting little amount of ETH

Answer (score 0):

The pepe coin you swapped to eth has no liquidity. Seems like a scam token

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i thought, but when you scan the contract it does look trustable. This is an old coin that was forgotten